# simple servelet Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, maven, servlets, jboss7.x

I'm new in java web developing. i'm adapt the project to working in server jboss 7.1.1. I write empty carcass servlet. Copy project.war to server. New file present project.war.deployed. Ok, but if i declare variable:

```
private org.h2.tools.Server server;
```

after copy project.war to server, present file project.war.failed. In the file pom.xml contains the library. Help me please.

log file:

```
09:00:39,380 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "project.war"
09:00:42,054 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/c:/jbpm-installer/content/project.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.4-1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
09:00:42,055 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/c:/jbpm-installer/content/project.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.4-1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
09:00:42,056 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/c:/jbpm-installer/content/project.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.4-1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
09:00:42,057 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in "/c:/jbpm-installer/content/project.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.4-1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
09:00:42,058 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/c:/jbpm-installer/content/project.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.4-1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
09:00:42,059 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Class Path entry jaxb-impl.jar in "/c:/jbpm-installer/content/project.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.4-1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
09:00:42,061 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/c:/jbpm-installer/content/project.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.4-1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
09:00:42,062 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/c:/jbpm-installer/content/project.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.4-1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
09:00:42,077 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext,org.springframework.beans.BeansException' for service type 'org.apache.cxf.bus.factory'
09:00:42,078 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser,org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer' for service type 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'
09:00:42,079 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser,org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer' for service type 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'
09:00:42,089 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for jbpm
09:00:42,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for org.jbpm.task
09:00:42,243 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."project.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."project.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "project.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class org.jboss.jbpm.webapp.servelet.HumanTaskStartupServlet with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.project.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/h2/tools/Server;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2387) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1796) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.tools.Server from [Module "deployment.project.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 15 more
09:00:42,256 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "project.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"project.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"project.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"project.war\""}}
09:00:42,458 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment project.war in 202ms
09:00:42,461 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."project.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."project.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "project.war"
09:00:42,463 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"project.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"project.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"project.war\""}}}}
```

Comment: Without seeing exception stack, no way to predict what is going on.

Comment: I found a log file. There seems there is more than one error. Can you tell what I'm doing wrong. My log file: [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6aJ6H5VNJ4XMWNtSk5pWXFzRVE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I noticed that the *. jar files attached to pom.xml copied to project.war / WEB-INF / lib. H2.jar but not copied. Although he has in pom.xml  file and Maven build the project without errors

Comment: you need to check why it is not lib folder? If is it in modules folder of jboss? you need to have H2.jar in one of these places to make your project run.

Answer (score 0):

Vladimir,

Apparently it seems the the ClassLoader which loaded the servlet is unable to find the class org.h2.tools.Server.

From the conversation you had with Nambari, it seems h2.jar is not copied to WEB-INF/lib folder. It make sense that you dont want to copy the file. Because, i believe Jboss AS 7.1.1 already comes with this jar as a module.

For non implicit dependencies (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments), i guess you need to provide an explicit dependency for this jar in your .war META-INF like below.

Dependencies: com.h2database.h2

For more info on this please take a look at "Explicit dependencies" section at http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-as-7/jboss-as-7-classloading

Good Luck.